# getItemOrNullObject() throwing Permission denied message

Tags: javascript, excel, office-js, office-addins

I am having an issue with the `Excel.WorksheetCollection.getItemOrNullObject(key: string)` function from the Office js API. As you can see from my code below, I am looking for a sheet named `Meta` in the current workbook and if it doesn't exist, it will create one.

My problem is that for some reason the `getItemOrNullObject` function doesn't return an Excel.Worksheet or null in absence of the Meta sheet. Instead, when I log the variable I get this message with a bunch of `Permission denied`s:

[image: screenshot]

I have unfortunately not seen this anywhere else online and I can't figure out where the issue lies.

Does anybody know how to solve this ?

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call context.sync() before you can read the object returned by a *OrNullObject method or property. Also, the object itself is not null. Instead, it the object doesn't exist in the workbook, the `isNullObject` property of the object is set to true. For details about all of this, see [OrNullObject methods and properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/application-specific-api-model#ornullobject-methods-and-properties).